# Window opened won't close

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, window

I have a window which opens on click.

```
function PopupManager() {
this.name = "_popupmanager_";
this.windows = {};
};

PopupManager.prototype.open = function(url, option, size, name) {
var url = "http://google.com" 
var option = "null, status=no, toolbar=no, menubar=no, titlebar=no, 
location=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no"
var size = 'height=200, width = 814'
this.windows[name] = window.open(url, option, size, name);
this.windows[name].focus();
};


PopupManager.prototype.closeAll = function() {
for (name in this.windows) {
  this.closeWindow(name);
}
 }


 PopupManager.prototype.closeWindow = function(name) {
if (this.windows[name]) {
    if (!this.windows[name].closed) {
        this.windows[name].opener.name="indexpage";
        this.windows[name].close();
    }
    delete this.windows[name];
 }
 };
```

//init

```
 document.getElementById("popupManager").onclick = function (e) { 
 e.preventDefault();    
 var popupManager = new PopupManager();
 popupManager.open('http://www.google.com', 'google');

}
```

And I am thinking this should close the same window.

```
 document.getElementById("closeIt").onclick = function (e) { 
 e.preventDefault();
 var popupManager = new PopupManager();
 popupManager.closeAll();
 popupManger.closeWindow();

 }
```

No console error & nothing happens.  Just won't close.

I was trying to use same <a> tag to open & close the window using if else statement but I couldn't figure it out.  So now I am trying to use two different  <a> tag, (yes, I know that's dumb) one to open & one to close but I can't even do that.

I can't even figure out what I am doing wrong here.

Any help will be greatly appreciated it. sigh...

Comment: Try to open the window with your same origin and let me know the results

Comment: I am opening the window w same origin; I've put in google.com for this question just so that this question doesn't get closed as too specific to the location or something like that.

Comment: Ok do you close the window within the same script opened it? Or from another script the window itself?

Comment: When you do `new PopupManager();` you instantiate a new instance, and `this.windows` is no longer what you think it is.

Comment: @Mouneer, I am opening & closing the window from the same document & same script.  No separate page or script involved.

Comment: Do you use the same reference to close? The var returned when open.. do you use it to close?

Comment: @adeneo, I kinda figured/guessed that might be the case but when I got rid of var popupManger line, of course I get undefined error.

I just can't figure out how to maintain the existing instance.  Can't think of a way to script it.  I was hoping that redeclaring the identical instance would maintain it but that's not the case.

Comment: so back to square one if you tell me to just use one button to open & close.  I couldn't figure that out; that's why I am trying to use two different buttons as an alternate method.

Comment: The solution is simple, just use an outside variable that isn't based on the instance, like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/5z0bmsff/

Comment: Store the reference globally and use it every where. A closure will be ideally to not polluting the window object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define a variable outside the popupManager that holds the windows, so you have access them later for closing.

You could wrap it an IIFE to create a closure as well.

```js
var windows = {};

function PopupManager() {
  this.name = "_popupmanager_";
};

PopupManager.prototype.open = function(url, option, size, name) {
  var url = "http://google.com"
  var option = "null, status=no, toolbar=no, menubar=no, titlebar=no, location = no, scrollbars = no, resizable = no ";
  var size = 'height=200, width = 814'
  windows[name] = window.open(url, option, size, name);
  windows[name].focus();
};


PopupManager.prototype.closeAll = function() {
  for (name in windows) {
    this.closeWindow(name);
  }
}

PopupManager.prototype.closeWindow = function(name) {
  if (windows[name]) {
    if (!windows[name].closed) {
      windows[name].opener.name = "indexpage";
      windows[name].close();
    }
    delete windows[name];
  }
};

document.getElementById("popupManager").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var popupManager = new PopupManager();
  popupManager.open('http://www.google.com', 'google');

}

document.getElementById("closeIt").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var popupManager = new PopupManager();
  popupManager.closeAll();
  popupManager.closeWindow();

}
```

```html
<button id="popupManager">Open</button>
<br />
<button id="closeIt">Close</button>
```

Another option would be to use

```
PopupManager.prototype.windows = {};
```

To keep the same variable accessible across instances.

Comment: Thanks!!  That works for if else statement I was trying to use in the first place.